# How do I store the values submitted in a form in the session?

Tags: 8, sessions

I want to submit a form and store the submitted values in the session. In Drupal 7 I just used `$_SESSION['key'] = $value;` but how do I correctly implement this in Drupal 8?

Comment: I'm not sure about this question. It's really vague, which generally isn't the sort of question we accept here. On the other hand, I can definitely see the same question showing up again and again, so perhaps it has enough value to stay. I've answered as well as I can below, but I'll also vote to close to see what the community thinks.

Answer (score 13):

In D8 the session data is provided by a symfony session object, which is attached to the request. See this comparison of D7 against D8:

**Drupal 7:**

```
function mymodule_session_counter_increment() {
  if (!isset($_SESSION['mymodule_count'])) {
    $_SESSION['mymodule_count'] = 0;
  }

  return $_SESSION['mymodule_count']++;
}
```

**Drupal 8:**

```
class MymoduleSessionCounter {
  function increment(Request $request) {
    $session = $request->getSession();
    $value = $session->get('mymodule_count', 0);
    $session->set('mymodule_count', $value + 1);

    return $value;
  }
}
```

Change record: [Access session data through the Request object](https://www.drupal.org/node/2380327)

Session management has not changed. You don't need to do anything, because Drupal starts a session for each request automatically and you can use it right away.

Examples how to get the session:

**Procedural**

In procedural code get the request from the static wrapper `\Drupal`:

```
$request = \Drupal::request();
$session = $request->getSession();
$session->set('mymodule_value', $value);
```

**Controller**

In a controller you can pull the request from the route argument stack by including a typed request parameter. An example from `UserController`:

```
  public function resetPass(Request $request, $uid, $timestamp, $hash) {          
    ...
    $session = $request->getSession();
    $session->set('pass_reset_hash', $hash);
    $session->set('pass_reset_timeout', $timestamp);
    ...
  }
```

It's not necessary to define the route parameter in the route definition. The request is always available.

**Form**

In a form method get the request from `getRequest()`:

```
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
    $session->set('mymodule_form_value', $form_state->getValue('value'));
  }
```

---

**Private Tempstore**

The private tempstore is not a replacement for sessions. It depends on the session id and it's not possible to use it without a session. So you can store the values directly in the session as well. Drupal core uses the private tempstore for big amount of data and only for authenticated users who already have a session. For anonymous users it's not easy to get a private tempstore started, because drupal uses dummy session id's until it starts a real session. If you start a private tempstore in custom code it has the wrong session id.

Comment: You say, "It's not necessary to define the route parameter in the route definition. The request is always available." But I get a runtime exception:
Controller "...\Controller\MatomoReportsController::reports()" requires that you provide a value for the "$request" argument. Either the argument is nullable and no null value has been provided, no default value has been provided or because there is a non optional argument after this one. in Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ArgumentResolver->getArguments() (line 78 of /var/www/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Controller/ArgumentResolver.php).

Answer (score 4):

To temporary store data in the session, in Drupal 8.5 and higher there is the [*tempstore.private*](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.services.yml/service/tempstore.private/8.6.x) service that, for example, is used from the node edit form to temporary store the node preview.

```
  public function form(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    // Try to restore from temp store, this must be done before calling
    // parent::form().
    $store = $this->tempStoreFactory
      ->get('node_preview');

    // Attempt to load from preview when the uuid is present unless we are
    // rebuilding the form.
    $request_uuid = \Drupal::request()->query
      ->get('uuid');
    if (!$form_state
      ->isRebuilding() && $request_uuid && ($preview = $store
      ->get($request_uuid))) {

      /** @var $preview \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface */
      $form_state
        ->setStorage($preview
        ->getStorage());
      $form_state
        ->setUserInput($preview
        ->getUserInput());

      // Rebuild the form.
      $form_state
        ->setRebuild();

      // The combination of having user input and rebuilding the form means
      // that it will attempt to cache the form state which will fail if it is
      // a GET request.
      $form_state
        ->setRequestMethod('POST');
      $this->entity = $preview
        ->getFormObject()
        ->getEntity();
      $this->entity->in_preview = NULL;
      $form_state
        ->set('has_been_previewed', TRUE);
    }

    /** @var \Drupal\node\NodeInterface $node */
    $node = $this->entity;
    if ($this->operation == 'edit') {
      $form['#title'] = $this
        ->t('<em>Edit @type</em> @title', [
        '@type' => node_get_type_label($node),
        '@title' => $node
          ->label(),
      ]);
    }

    // ...

  }

  /**
   * Form submission handler for the 'preview' action.
   *
   * @param $form
   *   An associative array containing the structure of the form.
   * @param $form_state
   *   The current state of the form.
   */
  public function preview(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $store = $this->tempStoreFactory
      ->get('node_preview');
    $this->entity->in_preview = TRUE;
    $store
      ->set($this->entity
      ->uuid(), $form_state);
    $route_parameters = [
      'node_preview' => $this->entity
        ->uuid(),
      'view_mode_id' => 'full',
    ];
    $options = [];
    $query = $this
      ->getRequest()->query;
    if ($query
      ->has('destination')) {
      $options['query']['destination'] = $query
        ->get('destination');
      $query
        ->remove('destination');
    }
    $form_state
      ->setRedirect('entity.node.preview', $route_parameters, $options);
  }
```

Before Drupal 8.5, the service is [*user.private_tempstore*](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21user.services.yml/service/user.private_tempstore/8.6.x), which will be removed in Drupal 9.0.

Since you want to store the submitted values, which I assume are used only for a limited period of time and aren't necessary anymore after the user logs in or logs out, I would use the same approach used from Drupal core to show a preview of a node before it gets created/saved. It has also the pro that deleting the data is automatically done.

Comment: I had come here to check if I was following the right approach for a multi-step submit process (i.e., exactly the example you have done, edit and then preview), so I was happy to have a confirmation. Also, thanks for the warning about `user.private_tempstore`, it will save me part of the headache when I finally migrate to Drupal 9 (I _know_, I'm late, but at least my project is for internal use only...)

Answer (score 3):

Here is an article on how to use the appropriate service to store data in the session: http://atendesigngroup.com/blog/storing-session-data-drupal-8

There are two methods described in the article, here's the first one which doesn't use dependency injection. (code is not mine)

> To set temporary data:

```
// For "mymodule_name," any unique namespace will do.
// I'd probably use "mymodule_name" most of the time.
$tempstore = \Drupal::service('user.private_tempstore')->get('mymodule_name');
$tempstore->set('my_variable_name', $some_data);
```

> To read temporary data:

```
$tempstore = \Drupal::service('user.private_tempstore')->get('mymodule_name');
$some_data = $tempstore->get('my_variable_name');
```

Comment: The services user.private_tempstore and user.shared_tempstore are deprecated in favour of tempstore.private and tempstore.shared. Code that uses the User module services should be updated to use the new services from core.

Answer (score 1):

Sessions (Drupal 8) are used via the simple Session implementation of SessionInterface interface.

Symfony sessions are designed to replace several native PHP functions. Applications should avoid using session_start(), session_regenerate_id(), session_id(), session_name(), and session_destroy() and instead use the APIs in the following section.

[Sessions Drupal 8](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html)

Example:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;

$session = new Session();
$session->start();

// set and get session attributes
$session->set('name', 'Yash');
$session->get('name');

// set flash messages
$session->getFlashBag()->add('notice', 'Profile updated');

// retrieve messages
foreach ($session->getFlashBag()->get('notice', array()) as $message) {
    echo '<div class="flash-notice">'.$message.'</div>';
}
```

Comment: You don't need to instantiate a session object or start a session. Drupal adds a session to each request in the bootstrap process in `Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session::handle()` and starts the session. You can get it with `$session = \Drupal::request()->getSession()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "\Drupal::service()".

To set temporary data:

```
$tempstore = \Drupal::service('user.private_tempstore')->get('mymodule_name');
$tempstore->set('my_variable_name', $some_data);
```

To read temporary data:

```
$tempstore = \Drupal::service('user.private_tempstore')->get('mymodule_name');
$some_data = $tempstore->get('my_variable_name');
```

You can refer to [this tutorial](https://atendesigngroup.com/blog/storing-session-data-drupal-8) for more details.

Comment: The services user.private_tempstore and user.shared_tempstore are deprecated in favour of tempstore.private and tempstore.shared. Code that uses the User module services should be updated to use the new services from core.

Answer (score 1):

Before you go rolling your own, see if the [Session Node Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/session_node_access) module does what you need.

Answer (score 0):

how about ? :

```
    $session = new Session();
    $session->set('key', 'value');

    $key= $session->get("key");
    var_dump($key);
```