# How can I use $_SESSION?

Tags: 8

I want to use this code in Drupal 8.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['loop'])) {
     $loop = $_SESSION['loop'];
} else {
     $loop = 0;
}
for ($count = 0; $count <= $loop; $count++) {
     $_SESSION['code'][$loop] = $code;
     $_SESSION['price'][$loop] = $price;
     $_SESSION['loop'] = $loop + 1;
}
```

This code worked correctly, but in Drupal 8 we should use this code.

```
// Setting a value.
$tempstore = Drupal::service('user.private_tempstore')->get('mymodule_name');
$tempstore->set('my_variable_name', $some_data);
```

```
// Getting a value.
$tempstore = Drupal::service('user.private_tempstore')->get('mymodule_name');
$some_data = $tempstore->get('my_variable_name');
```

I don't know how to change my code to use this service's API. How do I convert my code to use the *user.private_tempstore* service?

Comment: Where does it say "we should use" tempstore? That falls back to the session as well, so in the end you use the session too. Plus it doesn't sore something in the session, so you actually don't get a persistent session id. See http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/202027/difference-between-browser-session-and-drupal-session/202060#202060

Comment: So you say that I use the session directly ?

Comment: As I explained there, it depends on what kind of data you are storing, session is always loaded on every request. But yes. And I'd really like to know why you think this, it's not a rhetorical questions :)

Comment: @SiMoNe, yes use the session directly. The private tempstore doesn't work for anonymous users out of the box. You need some hacks to use it. But in most cases it's not worth the effort if you don't have tons of data. Example how to use the session in a form see my answer to your second question http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/228354/47547

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You listed all the elements you need. You just need to swap out the set and get you were originally using with the ones you provided.

This:

```
$loop = $_SESSION['loop'];
```

Will become this:

```
$loop = Drupal::service('user.private_tempstore')->get('mymodule_name')->get('loop');
```

And this:

```
$_SESSION['loop'] = $loop + 1;
```

Will become this:

```
\Drupal::service('user.private_tempstore')->get('mymodule_name')->set('loop', $loop + 1);
```

For your other elements, you can do the following.

This:

```
$_SESSION['code'][$loop] = $code;
```

Becomes this:

```
\Drupal::service('user.private_tempstore')->get('mymodule_name')->set('code', [$loop => $code]);
```

And this:

```
$_SESSION['price'][$loop] = $price;
```

Becomes this:

```
\Drupal::service('user.private_tempstore')->get('mymodule_name')->set('price', [$loop => $price]);
```

Comment: And others code ?!

Comment: Do the same thing.

Comment: $_SESSION['code'][$loop] . Its my problem . how can I use this array?

Comment: I updated my explanation.

Comment: Tnx . I test it . Is it work for anounymos users ?

Comment: error : The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
Error: Class 'Drupal\mymodule\Form\Drupal' not found in Drupal\mymodule\Form\BpayForm->buildForm() (line 43 of modules\mymodule\src\Form\Form.php).

Comment: That error has nothing to do with the current question.

Comment: `\Drupal::service('user.private_tempstore')` will be deprecated in Drupal 9. From now on you can use `\Drupal::service('tempstore.private')`.