# Session not refreshing until the cache is cleared

Tags: 8, caching, sessions

I am trying to store data entered in the drupal custom form in order to display it in next page using session.

For the first time it is running perfectly, but for the second time it contains the same value in session which was entered previously.

After clearing caches (admin/config/development/performance/clear caches) it is working for the first time, retains the same problem.

```
/**
 * @file
 * Contains \Drupal\resume\Form\PaymentForm.
 */
namespace Drupal\resume\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Session\SessionManager;
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Session\SessionManagerInterface;
use Drupal\user\PrivateTempStoreFactory;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;


class PaymentForm extends FormBase {

    /**
* @var \Drupal\user\PrivateTempStoreFactory
*/
protected $tempStoreFactory;

/**
* @var \Drupal\Core\Session\SessionManagerInterface
*/
private $sessionManager;

/**
* @var \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface
*/
private $currentUser;

/**
* @var \Drupal\user\PrivateTempStore
*/
protected $store;

public function getFormId() {
    return 'payment_form';
}

public function __construct(PrivateTempStoreFactory $temp_store_factory, SessionManagerInterface $session_manager, AccountInterface $current_user) {
    $this->tempStoreFactory = $temp_store_factory;
    $this->sessionManager = $session_manager;
    $this->currentUser = $current_user;

    $this->store = $this->tempStoreFactory->get('mymodule.storename');
}

public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
    return new static(
        $container->get('user.private_tempstore'),
        $container->get('session_manager'),
        $container->get('current_user')
    );
}

  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

if ($this->currentUser->isAnonymous() && !isset($_SESSION['session_started'])) {
    $_SESSION['session_started'] = true;
    $this->sessionManager->start();
}


$form['pay_first_name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => ('First Name'),
);

$form['pay_last_name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Last Name'),
);

$form['address'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => ('address'),
);


$form['email_id'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('email_id'),
);

$form['actions']['#type'] = 'actions';
$form['actions']['payment_submit'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => $this->t('payment'),
  '#button_type' => 'primary',
);
return $form;
}


  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

  $payment_array['first_name'] = $form_state->getValue('pay_first_name');
  $payment_array['last_name'] = $form_state->getValue('pay_last_name');
  $payment_array['line1'] = $form_state->getValue('address');
  $payment_array['email'] = $form_state->getValue('email_id');

  $session = \Drupal::service('user.private_tempstore')->get('resume');
  $session->set('payment_details', $payment_array);
    $form_state->setRedirect('payment_redirect.form');
    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you clear the session after a successful purchase? Otherwise the data will persist until your session expires (by default approx. 2 weeks).

Comment: I have tried that too, Even though it is not refreshing.
Code :      $session = \Drupal::request();
                $session->getSession()->clear();
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you store in `$session` is not a session. A private tempstore is a different kind of storage for large amount of data, too big to have it preloaded in memory.

If you want to store a small amount of data, that does not exceed a few Megabytes, then use a session. You find the session attached to the request object:

```
$session = \Drupal::request()->getSession();
```

In a form you can get the session from the injected request stack. Use `$session->set()` and `$session->get()` to store:

```
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
    $session->set('payment_details', $payment_array);

  }
```

and retrieve the data:

```
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
    $payment_array = $session->get('payment_details', []);

    // make sure the form is not cached and this code is run on every request
    $form['#cache']['max-age'] = 0;

  }
```

---

You don't need to start the session. This is done by Drupal in the background for each request:

When finishing the response, Drupal checks if there is new session data and then starts a session to store the data (which implies setting a cookie). When the user with the session cookie comes back, then the session is restored from the database and is attached to the request.

More info [Drupal 8 and Session Management](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/133955/drupal-8-and-session-management/236493#236493)

Comment: Is there any library should be used for this?? I have tried this but while submitting the from it displays "website encounters an error"... Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, only the two lines of code, no services or libraries necessary. The request stack is already injected by extending FormBase. The error could be a typo, enable full  error messages in /admin/config/development/logging

Comment: The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
Error: Call to a member function getCurrentRequest() on null in Drupal\resume\Form\PaymentForm->submitForm() (line 128 of modules/resume/src/Form/PaymentForm.php).

Comment: Found the problem, the request stack is not set when you run submit. By using getRequest() it should work, see the edit.

Comment: Same problem....   Error: Call to a member function getRequest() on null in Drupal\resume\Form\PaymentForm->submitForm() (line 128 of modules/resume/src/Form/PaymentForm.php).

Comment: I've tested getRequest() in a form submit inside of a form class, it worked. But when it doesn't work for you, use the static `$session = \Drupal::request()->getSession();` instead, this should work everywhere.

Comment: By using this static, for the first time it is working but for the next time data's were not updating, What to do for this problem? please guide me...

Comment: You mean when you try to get the session data in buildForm()? This is probably because the form is coming from the cache and your code is not run. Try to disable caching of the form: `$form['#cache']['max-age'] = 0;`

Comment: I am trying to display the stored value in a custom block.. 
Code: 
 public function build() {
 $session = \Drupal::request()->getSession();
  $array = $session->get('payment_details');
$data  = '.$array['first_name'].';
return array(
            '#type' => 'inline_template',
            '#template' => '{{ content }}'.$data,
            '#context' => [
                'content' => ''
        ]);

Comment: then you have to disable caching of the block `return [ ..., '#cache' => ['max-age' => 0]];`

Comment: wow super, it is working and updating in the block for both admin and anonymous, Thank you so much!!!!!
But one thing, I have printed that stored value while loading the block. For admin it is updating but for anonymous user it is not updating. Why it is so??

Comment: For anonymous users without a session the block still gets cached by the page cache. But as soon as the user inputs data and gets a session cookie the block cache max-age should work.

Comment: getRequest should be available as `$this->getRequest()` unless you did not extend FormBase.

Comment: I just checked two custom forms I had built, and this works inside of `buildForm()`: `$uri = $this->getRequest()->getRequestUri();`.

Comment: Only due to page cache the printed array value is not updating ?? 
Can I use the same session array for further process (append the array data to API). It should be updating right ???

Comment: This is not drupal specific, anonymous traffic without a cookie is cached in many places, most times the request is not even leaving your pc, because the browser loads the page from its cache.

Comment: All code in Drupal share the same session. So you should be careful to name the session parameter to have no conflicts with other modules.