# How to make anonymous session data private

Tags: sessions

I am using this multi-step form example (https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-build-multi-step-forms-in-drupal-8/ ) for the basis of an online employment application using Drupal 8.  All applicants are anonymous users.  The Private Tempstore seems to be private to a user, but not to a session.  If two applicants are applying simultaneously from separate computers, their information will overlap and one person's social security number will show up on the other person's computer.  Not good.  How do I make the Private Tempstore private to the session, not just the user?  I am fairly new to drupal and would appreciate any help.

Comment: This question seems a little bit too broad. What have you tried so far? Is creating user objects programmatically on form submit an option? Just for mapping.

Comment: Store the data in the symfony session object directly, if it's not a ton of data too big to load in memory for each request of this session, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/133955/drupal-8-and-session-management/236493#236493