# Can I use KernelEvents::EXCEPTION to make exceptions for my own code?

Tags: redirection

I've written code for a custom module in my .MODULE file that looks like this.

```
function cookie_authentication_node_access(NodeInterface $node, $op, AccountInterface $account) {
  if ($account->isAnonymous() && $node->gettype() == 'page') {
    return AccessResult::forbidden()->cachePerPermissions();
  }

return AccessResult::neutral(); 

}
```

Basically, using an EventSubscriber, I want to create an exception for my own rule I made above (letting anonymous users access a certain page)...

Would the 'EXCEPTION' KernelEvent be the right path, or is it only for real uncaught exceptions?

Comment: These are two different exceptions. What you want to do is to add an exception to the logic expression, for example `&& $node->id() != 123`. The event is part of the PHP error handling, see https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Comment: Thanks. I'm also trying to redirect the anonymous user from an access form. For the access form, I built a config form for the password, but the actual access form has this code: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/287398/allowing-anonymous-user-based-on-condition How would I go about referencing this in my .MODULE file (or maybe I need to make an EventSubscriber for this?)

Comment: The answer there is correct, you need to set a session value, a cookie doesn't work in Drupal. When you then use this session value here, add this cache context: `->addCacheContexts(['session'])`